# Request for question migration reversal

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, migrated-questions

I believe the question [*Powershell - changing the value of an environnement variable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261431/powershell-changing-the-value-of-an-environnement-variable?noredirect=1) was incorrectly migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/562085/powershell-changing-the-value-of-an-environnement-variable).

How on Earth is this not programming or tool related? As far as I can see it is 100% on topic for Stack Overflow, and that is where it stands the best chance of getting a decent answer.

How did it happen? I think this was kicked off by a single user voting for migration, then three low rep (less experienced) users agreed (quite possibly because it made the Close Votes review queue), then some guy finished it off.

Could it get answered on Super User? Maybe. Should it be there? No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've reversed the migration.

While it would probably have been fine on SU as well, there was no reason for it to be relocated.

Comment: Thanks Shog - and thanks for the edit too :) (I should never have put that in).

Answer (score 3):

That was wrongly migrated since Powershell is programming.

It's like what happens to quite a few Excel questions, where people who don't do the work don't recognize the programming that it takes to get things done, and how worksheet functions are just another programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Command shells are an interesting beast. For instance here are three Powershell related questions. (Sorry they aren't perfect examples, didn't go searching)

- How do I restrict the value of the parameter to a function to a range in Powershell?
- How do I add a user to active directory in Powershell?
- How do I open a URL from Chrome reusing an existing window?

But it wouldn't be hard to place the second one as a Serverfault question, nor the last as a SuperUser question.

Your question is an odd one, there isn't anything particularly programming related to setting the environment variable to a specific value, other than being in Powershell. Serverfault might work, since you are configuring the environment on a server, but that is also a bit of a stretch. SuperUser is likely not quite a good fit since scripting isn't really their forte.

And this is all convoluted by the distributed nature of the site. Each person has their own view on what is appropriate.

I think I would have disagreed, since I wouldn't consider it SuperUser, and we could use more Powershell answers in general, but I am not surprised someone thought it didn't belong since scripting languages are such an odd case.

Comment: This one wasn't just about setting an environmental variable, it was about setting one that directly affects the execution [of SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (this alone makes SU an unlikely target for a migration).

Comment: *"Command shells are an interesting beast."* That's the key bit. These things have to be considered in their context. Programming context == programming question == good on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @slugster: I did say I thought SU was a bad destination. I would agree that it at first glance doesn't look like a fit for SO though, until you realize it doesn't fit anywhere. And I am unsure what the solution to that is.